# How to import sub-modules of a module using define in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, require, amd

I'm new to AMD and trying to use [react-context-menu](https://github.com/vkbansal/react-contextmenu) library. The docs for the library imports modules like ,

```
    import { ContextMenu, MenuItem, ContextMenuTrigger } from "react-contextmenu";
```

Now if I were to include the module using `define[]`, how would I do it  ?

`e.g` for including react I would do,

```
    define(["react"], function(React){

    });
```

What should I do if I also want to include `react-context-menu` and use it's submodules `ContextMenu, MenuItem, ContextMenuTrigger`?

```
    define(["react", "react-context-menu"], function(React, ??????){

    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should consider using CommonJS modules `var $ = require('jquery')` in conjunction with a module bundled instead, either [webpack](https://webpack.github.io) or [browserify](http://browserify.org).

Answer (score 0):

```
    define(["react-contextmenu"], function(ReactContextMenu){

       var ContextMenu = ReactContextMenu.ContextMenu;
       var ContextMenuTrigger = ReactContextMenu.ContextMenuTrigger;
       var MenuItem = ReactContextMenu.MenuItem;

    });
```

The sub-modules can be included using `.`(dot). `<module>.<sub-module>` worked for me.